# Как "превратить" html & js игру в .apk?

Tags: javascript, android, html5

Есть html & js игра написана с помощью phaser фреймворка, как теперь ее упаковать в .apk?

Comment: Попробуй Telerik платформу. Есть для VS, есть для веба.

Comment: Стоило бы указать уровень своих знаний в Android - разработке.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты - PhoneGap, Appcelerator Titanium, Intel XDK и другие.

Но зачастую проще найти программиста просто на Java под Android, который сделает эту работу вручную (в Activity кинет WebView, в Assets запихает HTML+JS, если еще серверный код есть - то не в Assets, а на хостинг или сервер, и все настроит), более того иногда даже проще освоить все это самому, -- чем копаться в этих PhoneGap, которые содержат массу недочетов и редко работают "с пол-тычка", и при этом никаких серьезных преимуществ для мелкого проекта не имеют.

Answer (score 0):

два самых ходовых:

1. [Apache cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) (на его основе потом Phonegap сваяли), кордова как-то ближе сердцу. На
   линуксе через консоль все с пол-тычка заводится
2. [Cocoon](https://cocoon.io/) - веб-интерфейс, интуитивно, понятно, быстро. Размер файла на
   выходе - 10-15мб